# SQL How to compare two dates from different tables and display info only if the dates are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I need to compare two dates from different tables  and display info if the dates are the same

```
Select f.AbsenceDate, st.StudentLastName, stc.CourseDate, c.CourseTitle,
case when f.AbsenceDate=stc.CourseDate then'missing'
else 'not the same date' End as 'date info'
 from factAbsence as f
Join dimStudent as st
on f.StudentID=st.StudentID
Join factStudentCourse as stc
on st.StudentID=stc.StudentID
Join dimCourse as c
on stc.CourseID=c.CourseID
order by f.AbsenceDate desc, CourseDate desc;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi for compare a date is this :

```
where datediff(minute,SendDate,getdate())<=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I would suggest that you store the dates as `INT` in your tables (YYYYMMDD, example 20140301) if you plan on having a `JOIN` condition on them. Then, simply `INNER JOIN` on the two date columns of the two tables and display the required information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get too many or just the missing results because the joins are not working correctly? Try this one (you could also use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`), you don't have to join the FactAbsence table.

```
SELECT st.StudentLastName, stc.CourseDate, c.CourseTitle,
   CASE WHEN stc.CourseDate IN (
      SELECT AbsenceDate FROM FactAbsence WHERE studentID = stc.StudentID
   ) THEN'missing'
   ELSE 'attended'
   END date_info
FROM dimStudent st JOIN
   factStudentCourse stc ON st.StudentID = stc.StudentID JOIN
   dimCourse c ON stc.CourseID=c.CourseID
ORDER BY stc.CourseDate DESC;
```